# manyToMany not working in listener with virtual property

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I have a manyToMany relation beetween "Lot" and "BailProprietaire"

When i get an entity "BailProprietaire", i see the entities "lot" linked
But when i get an entity "Lot", i don't see entities "BailProprietaire" linked

In lot.orm.yml, i have :

```
AppBundle\Entity\Lot:
type: entity
repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\LotRepository
table: lot
....
....
manyToMany:
    bauxProprietaire:
        targetEntity: BailProprietaire
        mappedBy: lots
```

In bailProprietaire.orm.yml, i have :

```
AppBundle\Entity\BailProprietaire:
type: entity
table: bail_proprietaire
repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\BailProprietaireRepository
....
....
manyToMany:
    lots:
        targetEntity: Lot
        inversedBy: bauxProprietaire
        fetch: LAZY
        joinTable:
            name: bail_proprietaire_lots
            joinColumns:
                bail_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
                lot_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

do you see something i miss ?

thanks

EDIT : Add php entity code

Lot.php

```
class Lot
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;



    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    private $bauxProprietaire;


    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bauxProprietaire = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }





    /**
     * Add bauxProprietaire
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\BailProprietaire $bauxProprietaire
     *
     * @return Lot
     */
    public function addBauxProprietaire(\AppBundle\Entity\BailProprietaire $bauxProprietaire)
    {
        $this->bauxProprietaire[] = $bauxProprietaire;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove bauxProprietaire
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\BailProprietaire $bauxProprietaire
     */
    public function removeBauxProprietaire(\AppBundle\Entity\BailProprietaire $bauxProprietaire)
    {
        $this->bauxProprietaire->removeElement($bauxProprietaire);
    }

    /**
     * Get bauxProprietaire
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getBauxProprietaire()
    {
        return $this->bauxProprietaire;
    }


}
```

BailProprietaire.php

```
class BailProprietaire
{


    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    private $lots;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->lots = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }



    /**
     * Add lot
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Lot $lot
     *
     * @return BailProprietaire
     */
    public function addLot(\AppBundle\Entity\Lot $lot)
    {
        $this->lots[] = $lot;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove lot
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Lot $lot
     */
    public function removeLot(\AppBundle\Entity\Lot $lot)
    {
        $this->lots->removeElement($lot);
    }

    /**
     * Get lots
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getLots()
    {
        return $this->lots;
    }

}
```

EDIT 2 : in fact, it works but not with the listener

in fact i see the entities "BailProprietaire" when i get a "lot" but when i flush data, i have a listener. In this listener, i call a virtual propertie of "Lot.php" where i have :

```
if (!empty($this->bauxProprietaire)) {
        ....
    } else {
        ....
    }
```

but $this->bauxProprietaire is always empty

Comment: Can you show us your PHP entity code ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found the problem.

When i do $this->bauxProprietaire, i have a "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection" but when i look the collection in this object, there is 0 element
[image]

but if i do $this->bauxProprietaire->toArray(), i see my relation

I don't understand why but it works